# Passing variables in classic ASP

Tags: variables, error-handling, asp-classic, parameter-passing, html

I am dealing with legacy code where there is an include of another ASP page.

```
<!--#INCLUDE virtual="/PAGE1.ASP"-->
```

to get a variable, say x, from that page, I beleive I would do:

```
x = Request.Form("x")
```

is that correct?

Also, are the variable names case sensitive for classic .ASP files?

Thanks so much.

Comment: In this case (see lengthy discussion below) the variable is really a built in object named "Err" that doesn't need to be defined and is globally available.  Changing the original question would make some answers not needed, however, "Err" doesn't need Request.Form -- however some of these answers may help others with similar problems and different variable names.  Thanks

Comment: Classic ASP variables are not case sensative.

Comment: @Frank If your using [tag:jscript] as your server-side scripting language in Classic ASP that statement is not entirely true.

Comment: Great point.  Other than MD5 or something very difficult to do in VbScript I have yet to see anyone really use Jscript in classic asp.

Comment: although this post was down-voted in my biased humble opinion it would provide very good discussion to someone completely new to classic ASP.  I was trying to learn classic ASP having not done it when it wasn't "classic" as I was doing C and C++ then, and have since added a lot of C# with occasional Matlab, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should think of the page as being built into one contiguous page, so that if you include a number of `.asp` files they will build up your finished page.

For instance, if you have three files:

**File_1.asp**

```
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

**File_2.asp**

```html
<p>This file will be included too!</p>
```

**File_3.asp**

```
<%Dim version
version = 1.1%>
```

...and include them in one core file...

**File_Output.asp**

```
<!-- #include virtual="file_1.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="file_2.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="file_3.asp" -->
<% Response.Write(version) %>
```

`File_Output.asp` will display the `version` variable defined in `File_3.asp`.

There's a nice little article about it [here](http://www.christopherjason.com/asp/includes-using-asp-classic/).

**-- EDIT --**

Just to add (having missed the question at the end of your post):

Case sensitivity depends on the scripting language used by Classic ASP.  With VBScript variable names are case **in**sensitive, whereas, with JScript (which, syntactically, is very much like JavaScript) variables *are* case sensitive.

Also, to address the `Err` object:

There's a great little piece [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692852.aspx), but to get to the nitty-gritty, you need to wrap your code in an error catching block like so:

```vbs
On Error Resume Next    '<-- This line starts trapping errors
    ...
On Error Goto 0         '<-- This line stops trapping errors
```

If an error does occur in this block you need to deal with it.  Unlike ASP.NET, Java, etc. etc., you are not told that there is an error; there is no nice `Try...Catch` wrapper to handle the errors nicely.  You must kind of *predict* where the error will happen.  Usually it's obvious. If you have database manipulation in your script it's a good idea to test for errors directly after your data read or write.  To check for errors is simple - you test the `Number` property of the `Err` object:

```vbs
On Error Resume Next    '<-- This line starts trapping errors
    'Some database manipulation...
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ... 'Handle the error
    End If
On Error Goto 0         '<-- This line stops trapping errors
```

This can be expanded to take into account different error messages:

```vbs
On Error Resume Next    '<-- This line starts trapping errors
    'Some database manipulation...
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1
            ... 'Handle the error
        Case 2
            ...
        Case 3021 'No data returned
            Response.Write("No data was returned.")
    End Select
On Error Goto 0         '<-- This line stops trapping errors
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No point in asking that @Paul, but its a very detailed succinct answer. +1

Comment: Thanks Lanky - appreciated. :o)

Answer (score 1):

If you had something like `<input type="text" value="something" name="x"/>` on the first page then yes, `request.form(x)` will grab that value presuming the form has a method of `post`

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp

Comment: Sorry, it isn't declared that way.

Comment: x is apparently an object for holding events, because it uses a ".raise" event.  I am using VS 2010 to look at this file, and it actually was created in VS 6; I'm not sure whether the project file defines these ... anyway would an object be automatically available to another file.  This one's purpose is to raise errors apparently...

Comment: anyone have any thoughts on that situation?  Where are definitions usually "kept" just within the .asp file or somewhere else?  I'm sort of new to classic ASP .... and this is legacy code.

Comment: @JosephDoggie The object you are referring to is the `Err` object reference what that has to do with `x` I don't know. The `Raise()` method is a method of the `Err` object that allows you to raise your own errors. Seriously RTFM or at least show some code to give us all some context!

Comment: Please be kind when answering this question.

Comment: @JosephDoggie Please post some relevant code when asking this question.

Comment: @JosephDoggie The RTFM comment is purely from the view that when I start looking at a new technology first thing I do is research it read all the tutorials and books I can get my greesy mits on before I'd even consider asking for help. `Err` is a reserved object and as such is mentioned heavily in the VBScript Reference. All this however is still completely outside of the scope of your original question (which is the point I was making before). Apologies if my comments have offended you, that was not my intention.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `PAGE1.ASP` declares a variable such as `dim foo`, that variable is global and the parent page can access it via `foo`, e.g. `foo = "bar"`.