# ASP SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, connection-string

```vb
 <%
 DIM objConn
 Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=123.123.12.123,1234;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=Usernm;Password=abcd1234;"
 objConn.Open

 DIM mySQL

 mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [User ID]='1'"

 DIM objRS
 Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 objRS.open(mySQL, objConn)

 Response.Write objRS("FullName")

 objRS.Close
 Set objRS = Nothing
 objConn.Close
 Set objConn = Nothing
 %>
```

I want to connect to a SQL Server Database, read the data and close the connection. I have studied the examples and came up with this. But its not working. Please guide me. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the name of your SQL server? You should be using this rather than an IP and port (as bummi has succinctly stated!). Also, it's a good idea to put in error trapping so you can capture. Check out [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129183/passing-variables-in-classic-asp/26137258#26137258).

Comment: @Paul I've got no issue with using IP and port, that's just the method they have chose. What I do have an issue with is where the heck is your `Provider` or `Driver` attribute in the connection string (your not using the .NET Framework Data Provider)?, look at [SQL Server connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to see how connection strings should be formatted *(based on provider / driver)*. Also remember to set `Network Library=DBMSSOCN` if your using IP. **Might also help if you specify what version of SQL Server you are using.**

Comment: The IP is just an example. I have changed the connection string to "Data Source=123.123.12.123,1234;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Users;User Id=Usernm;Password=abcd1234;" But its still not working. Is there a way to know which line is the error? like in visual basic?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```vb
Dim rs, dbConn

Function OpenDB()
    Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbConn.ConnectionTimeout = 300
    dbConn.CommandTimeout = 300
    dbConn.Open "Data Source=123.123.12.123,1234;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=Usernm;Password=abcd1234;"
End Function

Function CloseDB()
    Set rs = Nothing
    if ucase(TypeName(dbConn)) = "CONNECTION" then
        dbConn.Close
        Set dbConn = Nothing
    end if
End Function

Function OpenRecordSet(recset, tablename)
    Call OpenDB()
    Set recset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    recset.Open tablename, dbConn, 0, 1
End Function

Function CloseRecordSet(recset)
    Set recset = Nothing
    Call CloseDB()
End Function
```

Then use

```vb
<%
Call OpenDB()
sql = "select from mytable where this = 'that'"
Set rs = dbConn.Execute(sql)
if not rs.EOF then
      ' do your stuff!
end if
Call CloseDB()
%>
```

http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/database/datafunctions.asp?ID=AW

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am new to asp. I am not using asp.net. I am coding in classic asp. Where will I declare the functions you gave? In <script/> </script> ? Sorry if it was a silly question but I am new to this.

Comment: Why wrap the functionality?, all that added opening and closing fluff is unnecessary. [That article](http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/database/datafunctions.asp?ID=AW) is from the Aug 2000! and not a very good one.

Comment: ... because I find it easier to dump that in an include and let junior programmers to OpenDB when they need to. Also GetRows is fine in some instances, but not all

Comment: @JanuszJasinski Bold statement, but what instances are you referring to? Bottom line `ADODB.Recordset` is inefficient memory hog, except for identifying meta data on records I haven't found a use for `ADODB.Recordset` that can't be accomplished with an Array. This approach makes people lazy, calling `OpenDB()` at top of a page (maybe even in `#include`) and then adding `CloseDB()` at the bottom of the page. The `ADODB.Connection` is often then open for the duration of page using a connection to the database that is not necessary.

Comment: OpenDB and CloseDB is also called when needed. Sometimes I won't know the order of the columns as it can be random so not sure how to access the column I want in an array unless you can enlighten me!

Answer (score 1):

Some answers have suggested wrapping logic into functions there is no need for this.

It's just a lot of fluff that isn't needed, just use the `ADODB.Command` object. There are hundreds of ways to approach this but a method I have found to work time and again is let the `ADODB.Command` object do the work then return your results into an `Array` using `.GetRows()` method of the `ADODB.Recordset` object.
That way you can close off both the `ADODB.Recordset` and `ADODB.Command` objects quickly and work just with the `Array`.

```vb
Dim conn, cmd, rs, sql, data, search

'Assume value to query comes from a Request Collection.
search = Request("myvalue") & ""

conn = "Data Source=123.123.12.123,1234;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=Usernm;Password=abcd1234;"
sql = "select from mytable where this = ?"
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
  'No need to handle connection let ADODB.Command create and destory it.
  .ActiveConnection = conn
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = sql
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@myparam", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))
  .Parameters("@myparam").Value = search
  Set rs = .Execute()
  If Not rs.EOF Then data = rs.GetRows()
  Call rs.Close()
  Set rs = Nothing
End with
Set cmd = Nothing
'ADODB.Connection is closed when ADODB.Command is destroyed.

If IsArray(data) Then
  rows = UBound(data, 2)
  For row = 0 To rows
    'Return first column of the current row
    Call Response.Write("First Column of Row " & row & " is '" & data(0, row) & "'<br />"
  Next
Else
  Call Response.Write("No records")
End If
```

Comment: Thats Better. Thanks. I am new to this.