# Convert the returned query from database to array [classic asp]

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am trying to convert the results which are being returned into an array in classic asp.

```
    <%strSQL="select tblGMFundingMechanism.Name,tblGMFundingMechanism.GMFundingMechanismID from tblGMFundingMechanism inner join tblGrantMakerProgram on tblGrantMakerProgram.GMFundingMechanismID = tblGMFundingMechanism.GMFundingMechanismID where GMID="&Session("GMID") %>
<%
     rst = connect.Execute(strSQL) 
%>
<option value="<%=rst("GMFundingMechanismID")%>" ><%=rst("Name")%></option>
```

Comment: See: [GetRows Method (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26278209/692942).

Comment: Here is a very good article that will help with the ADO getRows() method https://www.globalgraphics.co.uk/blog/classic-asp--recordsets-vs-getrows.html It should solve your question fairly quickly.